# MongoDB: How to store human names to do indexed case-insensitive queries on multiple names?

Tags: mongodb

**Quick Summary:**

I have a collection of documents where each document has an array of names; when the user types in a list of names I want to find all documents which have all of the user entered names in the document's name list.  Hitting indexes would be preferable, since the current strategy we're using takes seconds.

**Background:**

I'm trying to improve the performance of our queries against patient names.  Human names are complicated, giving me two big problems:

1. People have multiple names.  Or maybe they don't.  And they will probably give them in a random order
2. Human names are not case-sensitive (at least, we assume queries for them should not be), and mongodb doesn't currently support [case-insensitive indexes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90).

To work around problem #1, we're splitting the patient name and storing it as an array.  To work around problem #2, we lowercase the name before splitting it.  We're also sorting the array lexicographically (not sure if this is required?).

So these 'names' all become ["dupe", "uid"] in our documents:

- "UID^DUPE"
- "UID, DUPE"
- "UID DUPE"
- "DUPE UID"

Then, we can make a query which will hit the index:

```
db.mycollection.find({"data.crunchedName":/^dup/}, {_id:0, "data.crunchedName":1}).explain()
```

Which hits the index according to explain():

```
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor data.crunchedName_ multi",
"nscanned" : 13,
"nscannedObjects" : 12,
"n" : 12,
"millis" : 0,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"indexBounds" : {
    "data.crunchedName" : [
        [
            "dup",
            "duq"
        ],
        [
            /^dup/,
            /^dup/
        ]
    ]
}
}
```

Though for whatever reason I can't get it to display as "index only".  I don't think that will be important in practice.

If I try to use $and to bind more than one name, only the first name hits the index.  So there's a potential performance difference depending on the ordering of names.  I think this must be because there isn't a way to specify an index on pairs of things in a list.  I'm not sure you would even want to do that, since the index would be large.

**My Actual Question:**

Is this a decent approach?  Are there other options which wouldn't have performance issues if the user decided to type something like "S Alexander"?  Is there some canonical way of solving this problem using mongo that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Could you narrow this down into one, two or several, but more specific questions? Right now I'm unable to answer you, since I don't see what your specific problem points are. If you feel like you would need a more thorough code review, I'd suggest posting to If you want to review your code, I'd suggest you to posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more specific.  I'm wondering A) if this is even the right approach to dealing with ill-formatted names, and B) if there's anything I can do about the ordering dependent performance of this strategy.  It seems like it could be possible to know that "Alexander S" would be faster than "S Alexander" based on the bounds of the indexes of those queries.  I'm not sure if mongo could figure that out automatically, of if I could do it before issuing the actual query.  Or if I should just do a quick optimization like put the longer one first and call that good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different approaches you could consider as far as indexing with MongoDB.

#### Multi-key index

A common approach to indexing names and variations is to implement a multi-key search based on an array of search terms (as it appears you have done).  There is also an example of this in the MongoDB manual: [Model Data to Support Keyword Search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-keyword-search/).  With this approach you can index multiple relevant keywords to search on, and have control over the additional keywords.  The indexed words are typically stored in lowercase with common variations so you do not have to use a regular expression match.  [Regular expression matches](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) can only use an index efficiently if the regular expression is case-sensitive and has an anchor (^) at the beginning of the match string.

#### MongoDB 2.4 text search

MongoDB 2.4 introduced a new [text search feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/) which could also help with your use case.  This feature is still considered "beta" for the 2.4 release and has to be [explicitly enabled](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/).  The *text* indexes are case-insensitive and search results are returned in ranked order.  If you include multiple fields in the text index (for example, "last_name" and "first_name") you can also set [field weights](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/) to use in calculating relevance.  It is worth noting that the text search feature includes [language-based stemming](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search/#text-search-languages) which helps with relevance for normal searches (where multiple words can share a common root) but probably won't be as useful for matching patient names (where you might want a fuzzier match in case the name has been entered incorrectly).

#### Fuzzy matching for patient names

For name matching there are several common [phonetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) for implementing "sounds like" matching.  These have varying effectiveness depending on cultural differences such as spelling, pronunciation, and languages used within your corpus of names.

A good overview article is [Using Fuzzy Matching to Search by Sound with Python](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/how-tos/phonetic-hashing/index.html), which covers:

- [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)
- [NYSIIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NYSIIS)
- [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone)

#### Suggested approach

I think your best approach would be to use a multi-key index in conjunction with a phonetic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a reasonable approach.  One alternative you might try would be to store *all* the permutations in the document so you can avoid the `$and` operation.  You could perhaps also store the initial plus last name variants allowing an exact match instead of a starts-with regex.

Some records would have many permutations but most, I assume would have just two names and few permutations, e.g.

```
["John Smith", "Smith John", "J Smith", "John S"]
```

This approach might also allow you to store some common alternatives, e.g. Catherine, Cat, Kate.  Or you could handle that by mapping all alternatives to some canonical form.

There are other tricks you can do with RegEx searches to [find partial matches](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/11/mongodb-substring-search-with-a-difference/) but I don't think that will help in this case.